# Access Community from a different Salesforce Org

Tags: community, contact, customer-community, login, access

I have a customer community in an enterprise edition Salesforce org (say A). My contacts from this Salesforce org A logs in to this community and access some custom objects as well (through community VF pages).

Now, I have another Salesforce org (say B).  How can I let the contacts from this org B access the same community?  The solution I can think of is, create a duplicate copy of this contact into Salesforce org A and access it and somehow keep the contacts in both orgs in sync, but this isn't a great one!

Is this possible at all without duplicating the contacts into my first org?

Directions please!

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this would be to do a single sign on between two orgs .You can treat one org as IDP while other as a SP org .Once single sign on is enabled ,you can use JIT to automatically provision users on the other org .This would also allow you to log in from one org to other

Comment: okay, got it.  But there are some actions performed by the contact in the community like creating custom objects records that will be tagged to the contact.  What happens to those records? Where do I tag them? because the contact record doesn't really exists in the 2nd org, right.

Comment: When a user is provisioned , a new contact record will be created as it is communities